# Function vs new Function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, new-operator

What si difference between calling Function constructor with new and without it in front of keyword Function.

```
 var result = Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
 var myResult = new Function('a','b', 'return a + b');
```

I know about new operator and that it:
Create a blank, plain JavaScript object
Links (sets the constructor of) this object to another object;
....

But that is make sanse in this situation with constructor function

```
 function Car(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

 const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);
```

I know that in this situation each time new car instance will be crated.

But in above example what is difference between result and myResult?
Please give me a little bit better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. The function constructor looks (more or less) like this:

```
 function Function(...args) {
   if(!(this instance of Function)) {
      return new Function(...args); // your first call ends up here, so it's like your second
   }
   // ... further magic
 }
```

So no matter wether you call or construct `Function`, a new function object gets created and returned, the same way a car object gets created when you contruct `Car`.

Comment: i tried to create another function ('Function1') like Function constructor, it wont behave same. Even as you mentioned that first call ends after 'return new Function(...args);' , it wont ends here.


This is what i am trying to do;

function Function4(...args) {
   if(!(this instanceof Function)) {
      return new Function4(...args); // your first call ends up here, so it's like your second
   }
   // ... further magic

  return 12;
 }

i am expecting 
new Function4() // return 12
Function4 // return 12

Answer (score -1):

```
result = function(){};
```

Places a reference to an anonymous function into result. result points to a function.

```
myResult = new function(){};
```

Places a reference to a newly constructed instance of an anonymous constructor function into myResult. myResult points to an object.